# Can Node API build on top MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am aware that node APIs can be built on top of NoSQL DB can node API be built with MySQL DB? Please also share some good resources.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources, tutorials, tools, or libraries recommendation is off-topic in here

Comment: You can, perhaps https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp would be a place to start. Also https://sequelize.org/.

As mentioned, this isn't the best place to ask these kind of questions. Maybe look for a Node js chatroom somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is Javascript server side runtime. So You can connect to all the data source you can with java/.Net etc. So yes, you can use MySql with node.js.

reference:
[Node with MySQL](https://medium.com/@avanthikameenakshi/building-restful-api-with-nodejs-and-mysql-in-10-min-ff740043d4be)